# Excel web add-in: How to detect ribbon click events?

Tags: excel, office-js

I am working with the Excel JavaScript API and I am trying to trigger an event when the user clicks on any ribbon button or tab, and get which button or tab was clicked, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a supported scenario in Office.js. Your add-in is running in a sandboxed environment (either within an IFRAME or an embedded browser, depending on the platform). Even in cases where the ribbon buttons are part of your add-in, the communication is one-way (clicking the button will trigger loading a page or firing a function from your add-in).

Comment: And Office.js is the only way to create an excel web add-in and interact with the document?

Comment: Office Web Add-ins and Office.js refer to the same thing, yes. This is the only cross-platform extensibility option today. Others such as VSTO have more options but only support the desktop version of Office for Windows

Comment: So, if I really need to implement this feature ( trigger an event when the user clicks on any ribbon button or tab, and get which button or tab was clicked), should I work with a VSTO add-in?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can intercept arbitrary ribbon button clicks using VSTO, I can only confirm that you cannot do this from a web add-in.